# Man In the High Castle - Pivotal Historical Differences to the "Alternate" Universe?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

What were the pivotal historical differences in the Man in the High Castle universe vs the "alternate" universe (our universe) where the Allies won? Is this ever alluded to in the show, as to how the Nazis and the Japanese managed to conquer the world, and how the Allies never really formed?

Comment: The "alternate" universe to which Mr. Tagomi travels is probably not "our" universe ; I think there were hints in the original novel of differences between that alternate universe and ours (could not remember which though). An idea of Philip K. Dick was that there are several "fake universes" that hide reality, and even travelling from one to the other does not mean we found the "only one true universe" yet.

Comment: I see. I thought the show was great! However the final ending scene of the series finale kind of alludes me as to its meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't recall which episodes specifically, but the two major events we are told:

- [Franklin D. Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt) was assassinated (presumably by [Giuseppe Zangara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Zangara)).
- The Nazis dropped an atomic bomb on Washington DC.

On a lesser scale, Hitler was watching the films, and thus learning from the ways he was defeated in alternate universes.

Comment: Ah. So FDR's assassination would have led to no New Deal and the US would have been in economic depression longer. I would guess this would have led Great Britain to have to fight the war by herself as the only major power with any real military force, only to later get pounded out of existence.

Comment: Depends upon WHEN FDR is supposed to have been assassinated. During his governorship of NY? A day after being elected president for the very first time? Well into his third term?

Comment: @Alex February 15, 1933